# Max date of jquery datepicker not working

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, datepicker

I have following code, I am trying to disable future dates but that does not work with jquery datepicker.

The code is

```
$('#dp_my').datepicker({
       maxDate: new Date
   }).on('changeDate', function(e){
       var y = e.date.getFullYear(),
       _m = e.date.getMonth() + 1,
       m = (_m > 9 ? _m : '0'+_m),
       _d = e.date.getDate(),
       d = (_d > 9 ? _d : '0'+_d);
       $(this).text(m + '/' + d + '/' + y);
       $(this).datepicker('hide');

       $("#xyz").val(m + '/' + d + '/' + y);
   });
```

Any pointers ?

Comment: Is `maxDate` a valid option for the datepicker library you are using?

Comment: If you're using the [eternicode](http://eternicode.github.io/bootstrap-datepicker/) datepicker, then `endDate` is the valid option.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$('#datepicker').datepicker({
    endDate: '-1d'
});
```

I was using boostrap